# Salvar database de outro HD

Tags: mysql

Tinha um HD principal com meu *webserver* - Apache, PHP, Mysql - mas deu problema e não conseguia mais acessar. Precisei formatar um novo HD e reinstalar meu ambiente. O problema é que não deu tempo de exportar a database.

Instalei tudo no novo HD, e ja tentei entrar na linha de comando do HD antigo para exportar, mas ele só roda no Mysql do HD novo.

Abri um *CMD* com o comando abaixo alterando a unidade **C:/** pela antiga, dei um `show databases` mas não funcionou.

`"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysql.exe" "--defaults-file=C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\my.ini" "-uroot" "-p" "--default-character-set=utf8"`

---

Não sei se fiz certo ou errei em alguma etapa, mas é possível, pela linha de comando, salvar a database que está em outro HD?

Comment: Tentou copiar a pasta `data` do MySQL no HD velho?

Comment: @rray são versões diferentes, teria problema?

Comment: Quais versões? em teoria o muda são as 'regras' o modo de armazenado não deve mudar mto de uma versão p outra(palpite). Se vc realmente precisa, não custa tentar.

Comment: Mais tarde vou fazer um backup e substituir a pasta pra ver se resolve e comento. Pela linha de comando não deveria ter acesso à DB correspondente?

Comment: @rray Se entrar pelo linux via Pen, será que consigo?

Comment: 1) não sei. 2) talvez :)

Comment: @rray nem achei a pasta `data`. Estou com a versão 5.7

Comment: Roda essa consulta `SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_Name = 'datadir'` qualquer coisa [olha aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17968424/1342547)

Comment: Abri o `mysql.exe` pelo prompt do HD antigo e a pasta `datadir` aponta para `C:/`. Vou tentar rodar o Linux depois se não der tento a troca da pasta. Valeu @rray

Comment: Vai parecer uma baita gambiarra, mas tentou simplesmente finalizar o mysql, copiar a pasta `/data` em mysql da instalação antiga e sobreescrever a nova e reiniciar o mysql?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento não tem risco de dar alguma desconfigurada já que são versões diferentes?

Comment: @PapaCharlie vixe, tem sim, melhor copie apenas os arquivos que representam as tabelas antigas. Na verdade eu já passei por isso, mas é uma coisa de caso a caso.